# Tried making a gif transparent, unoptomized I got a trail, optomized I got a grainy effect

Tags: gimp, transparency, gif, optimization

[image: Here is the gif after I optimized the gif and chose replace layer when exporting]

[image: Here is the gif unoptimized]

The first image is the gif unoptimized, the second image is the gif optimized when exported. Both images had the "replace layer" option selected. Any idea what I could do to get a middle ground with no trail and no grainy effect?

Comment: I can't really tell what you've done wrong. I can only take a guess. Are you sure the image needed to be unoptimized?  Not all GIFs are optimized. If you share the original, I would be able to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get back to the original image. The frames in the second image contain a trail of the previous frames. This is your top frame layer alone:

[image]

As far as I can tell the optimization done by Gimp is that pixels in a frame that are identical to those of the previous frame are replaced by transparency. The result is then auto-cropped. But the whole process assumes that the frames are initially all opaque, this doesn't play well when there are transparent parts.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So how would I go about getting back to the original image? This is my first time working with gifs in gimp so I apologize if I'm asking dumb questions lol

Comment: What I mean is that you likely mishandled it in Gimp so you have to go back to what it was before you started editing it with Gimp. Ideally you still have it somewhere... or you have the URL and can retrieve it again.

Comment: Oh gotcha, yeah I have the original gif saved. What should I do differently when I go back to edit it again to avoid this problem?

Comment: Before everything: `Filters>Animation>Unoptimize`, then make the frames transparent, then  File>Export, give name in .GIF, tick 'Export as animation', and force `Replace` mode on all frames. All this assuming that the file you start with is in a decent shape of course.